# Error: Cannot find module './build/index.js' from '/usr/src/app'

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hello I am trying to deploying the build folder to docker and I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './build/index.js' from '/usr/src/app'

The dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM node:14
EXPOSE ${PORT}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ADD build .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

the npm start script is the following:

```
"start": "tsnd ./build/index.js",
```

And the files are in the following structure:

```
└── project
     ├── build/index.js
     ├── dockerfile
     ├── package.json
```

When I used the following command and copying everything didn't fail:

```
"dev": "env-cmd tsnd --respawn src/index.ts",
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `docker run --rm -it your-image bash` to get an interactive debugging shell in a temporary container based on your image, and looking around to see if things are in the right place?  (I suspect `index.js` is in the `app` directory and not `app/build`.)

Comment: Finnaly I do build on the cointainer, because docker doesn't copy the folder, thanks for the response.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES can you please share here what you did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM node:14-alpine
EXPOSE ${PORT}

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```